# Dynamic imports in Jest produce: SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jestjs

Can't figure out how to resolve these errors yet, Jest is complaining about dynamic imports like these:

```
const importModules = Promise.all([
      import('containers/HomePage/reducer'),
      import('containers/HomePage/sagas'),
      import('containers/HomePage'),
    ]);
```

Error message:

```
F:\react-boilerplate\app\store.js:49
      import('./reducers').then(function (reducerModule) {
      ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

You can find all of the details here: https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/pull/1358

Comment: what does your `.babelrc` looks like?

Comment: It looks like this: https://github.com/Dattaya/react-boilerplate/blob/fd0aa64bd074426541cf0ba675431b389794832f/package.json#L51

Comment: Have you tried to use the same plugins for prod and test. Seems like babel cant compile the stuff with your babel `env.test` settings

Comment: Thank you @AndreasKöberle for your suggestion, I added `babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node` plugin to the list of plugins in test environment and the error was resolved for the most parts. I guess dynamic `import()`s can't be polyfilled so the only choice for node is to transform them to `require` inside a `Promise`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Installing `babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node` solved our problem. In addition, make sure that `babylon` (`babel` dependency) is at least `6.12.0`.

Also, we had a problem with Travis build because Travis cached `node_modules` and old `babylon` with it:

```
$ npm ls babylon
react-boilerplate@3.3.0 /home/travis/build/mxstbr/react-boilerplate
├─┬ babel-core@6.21.0
│ └── babylon@6.11.1
├─┬ babel-eslint@7.1.1
│ └── babylon@6.14.1 
├─┬ jest-cli@18.0.0
│ └─┬ istanbul-lib-instrument@1.3.0
│   └── babylon@6.14.1
```

, so we had to turn the cache off with: `cache: false`

Comment: I had a similar issue where Jest tests would run fine locally (with the `@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` plugin) but they would fail during CI. Adding `babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node` worked (because the CI runs on node).  See https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5920#issuecomment-444112504

Answer (score 0):

It looks like jest cant compile your files with the babel settings for `test` in your `.babelrc` file. You need to have the same settings for `prod` and `test`